# What's the difference between a 5$/mo and a 20$/mo web hosting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-hosting

I need to put on the Internet my portfolio and a few other projects (http://myportfolio.com/website1 for example). I was thinking of a low budget web hosting like Bluehost.

I'm learning Ruby on Rails and I plan to continue on this road, and [Bluehost](https://www.bluehost.com/) does support Ruby on Rails and PostgreSQL (which I'm using). But I saw on the Internet people recommending Heroku (which seems a bit pricy for the relatively little exposition I'll have) or [Linode](http://www.linode.com/), Slicehost, which are more like 20$/mo or more.

Which one should I take, and above all what's the main difference that justifies the gap in the prices? (I heard about hosting Rails apps in a "shared environement" not being recommendable, etc.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the kind of question that will have a different answer every year (or 3 months), since hosting providers change their offerings constantly to be competitive. I'll give you a few of the common gotchas for cheap hosting that seem to stay constant:

- Support is not timely or effective. Note that some 24x7 support merely gives you access to people who will be unable to solve all but the most common problems, and will need to escalate you to higher support tiers.
- Bandwidth is limited or throttled. It is common for many providers to offer very large ("unlimited" even!) amounts of bandwidth, but in practice you are unable to reach the cap due to throttling or overall limitations of the networking throughput.
- Resources overshared with other customers on the same servers.
- Software that can run on the account is very limited or lacks configuration options.
- Add-on costs for common features like SQL server, email.
- High setup fee.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you need a very strong webhost for that. Heroku will do fine and it is free if you dont have a bigger database than 5 mb. Works fine with my projects. You can give it a try, it is easy and fast to setup and there are a lot of add ons you can take.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I buy a Bluehost web hosting, can I redirect, let's say, www.myportfolio.com/website1 to my app hosted freely on heroku (http://quiet-wind.etc.herokuapp.com)?

Comment: yes you can! http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2009/10/7/heroku_casts_setting_up_custom_domains/